# How I can make a JOIN equivalent in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections, one named friends and the other called users, let me show you my documents:

socialNet.friends :

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("64a23d40a2801bfb06c90675"),
 user: '64a23d40a2801bfb06c90672',
 friend: [
   {
    id: '64a23d3aa2801bfb06c9066d',
    name: 'marco'
   },{
    id: '64a23d30a2801bfb06c90668',
    name: 'angel'
   }
  ]
 }
```

socialNet.users:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("64a23d40a2801bfb06c90672"),
 user: 'link',
 email: 'dill1@live.com',
 password: '$2a$08$sne/GtCXNn/31Reete6nCer3/fUhztCgjrERFx1Cjy4wbm1P4eAgq',
 status: 'offline'
}
```

my idea is to get something like this:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("64a23d40a2801bfb06c90672"),
 user: 'link',
 email: 'dill1@live.com',
 status: 'offline',
 friend: [
   {
    id: '64a23d3aa2801bfb06c9066d',
    name: 'marco'
   },{
    id: '64a23d30a2801bfb06c90668',
    name: 'angel'
   }
  ]
 }
```

So first I try to join both collections, and then make the right corrections to get to this result, if you can se my `_id` in Users is my `user` in Friends, so what I end up with is this:

```
await User.aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: "64a23d40a2801bfb06c90672" } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "friends",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "user",
                as: "friendDetails"
            }
        }
    ]).then(
        document => {
            console.log(document)
            res.status(201).json({
                message: document
            })   
        }
    )
```

This query is a result of reading the documentation of mongodb and teh result is this `[]`, i try in other way but te result is just this `friendDetails:[]`, Im really knew at this, thank you if you can teach me how for further proyects and nice day or night

Comment: The problem is in `friends` collection, the `user` field is string type. Thus, when matching `_id` field from `users` collection which is `ObjectId` type, the `friendDetails` array returns empty array. Cast the `user` field to `ObjectId` should be worked.

Comment: You were right, is done now, thank you very much..!!!! :D